# How can I define a consumer group into Azure IoT Hub?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

In order to consume data on Azure IoT Hub into Microsoft Power Bi I have created a Stream Analytics job. From the documentation, i found out that "Each stream Analytics Job input should be configured to have its own consumer group". So i have to create into my Azure IoT Hub a consumer group. How can I define a consumer group into Azure IoT Hub?

Comment: [If not specified, Stream Analytics jobs will use the Default Consumer Group to ingest data from the IoT Hub](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs.md#consumer-groups-1) or as @shachar points out, you can create a new consumer group.

Answer (score 5):

In order to create a new consumer group go to your Iot Hub instance in Azure.

Go to Endpoints tab, choose the correct Built-in endpoints, in case it's device to cloud messages it should be Events (message/Events). 
There you can add a consumer group.

Comment: If you're using an ARM template to create or update an IoT Hub, your can specify the consumer groups in the template. See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-rm-template-powershell